# how to use the Gale-Church algorithm in Python-NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp, alignment, nltk, text-alignment

The gale-church algorithm is available in the python-NLTK but can anyone show me an example of how to call the function within a python script? i'm clueless about how to do that.

http://code.google.com/p/nltk/source/browse/trunk/nltk_contrib/nltk_contrib/align/align.py?r=8552&spec=svn8552

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After giving up on using the `Gale-Church` aligner in NLTK contribution, i wrote my own =)
http://code.google.com/p/gachalign/ (Feb 2013)

Please use this updated version of the Gale-Church aligner: https://github.com/alvations/NTU-MC/blob/master/ntumc/toolkit/gale_church.py (Sept 2014)

Comment: It does not seem to work for the inputs quoted in the Gale-church paper:\

Comment: Thank you for the updated code. But it is not producing result as shown in the english-french example of the paper

Comment: yes, i don't think it's the algorithm / implementation per se but the data you're testing on.

Comment: These are the input I am using [eng.txt](http://pastebin.com/Xk6DtZMB), [french.txt](http://pastebin.com/ZhNpEHxr) and ran the program as "python gale_church.py eng.txt french.txt" and got [output](http://pastebin.com/b7n6pPTY) while the output shown in the paper is [out](http://pastebin.com/EAv0GEVf)